# Click on button doesn't work in IE9 but no error message (it works in chrome)

Tags: java, javascript, html

I want to try [this applet.](http://www.openoces.org/demo/entrance_opensign.html)

when clicking on button continue in `IE` it doesn't work whereas in `chrome` it does.

Why? There's no error message.

Comment: Check your JavaScript console.

Comment: I can't see any: doesn't pop up only when there is an error and since no error is showing up.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "doesn't work"?  It loaded for me im not sure if that was the problem you were having or something specific about the applet.

Answer (score 3):

In your JavaScript console (in IE9), you are getting an error.

> Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'

IE < 9 doesn't support `String.prototype.trim`.  You page is running in "Quirks mode" which means it's running like it's in an old version of IE.

Try to force IE to run the page in the correct mode by adding this to the `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

You should also add a [doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Declaration) to your page.  Here's the HTML5 one (put this at the top of the page (before `<html>`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```